# Getting Disqus comments With Blogger API

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, blogger, disqus

I'm currently using the `Blogger API` to retrieve blog posts and display them on my app. I can add the following code into my site app to add the Disqus comments and it's posting module, but how would I get the `PAGE_IDENTIFIER` and `PAGE_URL` so that the comments from the Blogger site mirror onto my site app?

With the `Blogger API`, I am able to retrieve each blog post's unique `ID` and the `URL`.

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
    /**
     * RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
     * LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
     */

    var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = PAGE_URL; // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
    this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
    };

    (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
        var d = document,
            s = d.createElement('script');

        s.src = '//codingbarrier.disqus.com/embed.js';

        s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `Disqus` will use the Blog's post `URL` only to track the comment thread, so using the `Blogger API`, you can get the post's `URL` and just set `this.page.url` in the generic Disqus script and it'll show the same comments from the specific blog post.